# Calling static method inside constructors php

Tags: php

```
public function __construct($docID) {

    self::getTranscriptionInfo($docID);

}

protected static function getTranscriptionInfo($docID) {
    $cache_dir = $this->cache_dir;
}
```

I get error"Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in". How to fix it?

1. I want to make getTranscriptionInfo() static
2. I want to call getTranscriptionInfo() inside construct.

Comment: Are you using `$this` inside the static method?

Comment: @DDomen yes. do you know how to call class property inside static method?

Comment: You cant. You must use a static variable or pass an instance of an object to your static method.